# Default route is not working with laravel and vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-vue

I am creating a single page application using laravel and vue. it's not loading index component on page load.

web.php

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {
return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Welcome.blade.php

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>      
    </div>
  <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

router.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter)
const routes = [
{ path: '/', component: require('./components/IndexComponent.vue') },
{ path: '/login', component: require('./components/LoginComponent.vue') }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
routes:routes,
mode:'history' 
})
export default new VueRouter({router})
```

app.js file

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
import vuetify from './vuetify';
import router from './router';

import Index from './components/IndexComponent'; 
import Login from './components/LoginComponent'; 

var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
vuetify,
components: {
    'index-component':Index,
    'login-component':Login
}
});
```

Index Component (IndexComponent.vue)

```
<template>
  <router-link to="/" class="nav-item nav-link">Home</router-link>
                <router-link to="/login" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</router-link>
 <router-view></router-view>
 </template>
```

Comment: can you share your web.php as well

Comment: Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any', '.*');

Comment: try `export default new VueRouter({router})` to `export default router`

Comment: First step, try to establish if the problem is in Laravel or vue. If you `return 'hello';` instead of your view, does it work?  There is no point adding a regular expression which matches anything, keep it simple, remove `->where('any', '.*')`.

Comment: What does `not loading index component` mean, exactly? 404? Server error? What does browser devtools show? Logs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Open your project in chrome and press Ctrl + Shift + I (Open console). Now after the login you can see that there is a warning which says: No match for favicon.ico. To solve this problem you go to your routes file and define a redirect:

```
{
    path: '/favicon.ico',
    redirect: '/user/dashboard'
}
```